# Can a (bounded) linear least-squares problem include a scale factor in its solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

I have a system of equations.

$$
\small
\begin{aligned}
(1 - p_0)u_0 + (q_0 - 1)v_0 + u_1 - v_1 = r_0 - c t_0 \\\\
(1 - p_1)u_1 + (q_1 - 1)v_1 + u_0 - v_0 = r_1 - c t_1 \\\\
(1 - p_2)u_2 + (q_2 - 1)v_2 + u_3 - v_3 + u_4 - v_4 = r_2 - c t_2 \\\\
(1 - p_3)u_3 + (q_3 - 1)v_3 + u_2 - v_2 + u_4 - v_4 = r_3 - c t_3 \\\\
(1 - p_4)u_4 + (q_4 - 1)v_4 + u_2 - v_2 + u_3 - v_3 = r_4 - c t_4
\end{aligned}
$$

Expressed in matrix form, the coefficient matrix can always be formulated as two adjacent block-diagonal matrices.

$$
\scriptsize
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - p_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & q_0 - 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
1 & 1 - p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & q_1 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 - p_2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & q_2 - 1 & -1 & -1 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 - p_3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & q_3 - 1 & -1 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 - p_4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & q_4 - 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_0 \\\\
u_1 \\\\
u_2 \\\\
u_3 \\\\
u_4 \\\\
v_0 \\\\
v_1 \\\\
v_2 \\\\
v_3 \\\\
v_4
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
r_0 - c t_0 \\\\
r_1 - c t_1 \\\\
r_2 - c t_2 \\\\
r_3 - c t_3 \\\\
r_4 - c t_4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This can, of course, be solved to get all $u_i$ and $v_i$.

My question is about the actual math but, for completeness, I am using the Python function `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear`, which supports bounds, because each of these has a lower bound of $0$ and a positive upper bound. Additionally, I am aware that the known block-diagonal shape allows this problem to be trivially divided into smaller sub-problems, which would be particularly desirable since my real problem has around 80 equations instead of the 5 shown. However, I leave it in this form because I also want to calculate the scale factor $c$ as part of one big solution.

To this end, the problem can be slightly rearranged.

$$
\scriptsize
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - p_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & q_0 - 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & t_0 \\\\
1 & 1 - p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & q_1 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & t_1 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 - p_2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & q_2 - 1 & -1 & -1 & t_2 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 - p_3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & q_3 - 1 & -1 & t_3 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 - p_4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & q_4 - 1 & t_4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_0 \\\\
u_1 \\\\
u_2 \\\\
u_3 \\\\
u_4 \\\\
v_0 \\\\
v_1 \\\\
v_2 \\\\
v_3 \\\\
v_4 \\\\
c
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
r_0 \\\\
r_1 \\\\
r_2 \\\\
r_3 \\\\
r_4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In my real problem, all $r_i$ start as $0$ (on the first iteration of my program) which means the trivial solution of setting $c = 0$ is always returned as the least-squares solution, all $t_i$ have no effect, and all all $r_i$ stay as $0$. What I really want is a way to get the largest $c$, up to its own positive upper bound $k$, while still finding a least-squares solution for everything else. I could add another row to the matrix and allow $c$ to simply target its largest possible value $k$ but I am not sure if this is a good idea. I think it will dominate the least-squares calculation, because $k$ can be quite large compared to everything else, and I am not sure how I would choose a sensible scaling for this to achieve the correct balance.

$$
\scriptsize
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - p_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & q_0 - 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & t_0 \\\\
1 & 1 - p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & q_1 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & t_1 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 - p_2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & q_2 - 1 & -1 & -1 & t_2 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 - p_3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & q_3 - 1 & -1 & t_3 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 - p_4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & q_4 - 1 & t_4 \\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_0 \\\\
u_1 \\\\
u_2 \\\\
u_3 \\\\
u_4 \\\\
v_0 \\\\
v_1 \\\\
v_2 \\\\
v_3 \\\\
v_4 \\\\
c
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
r_0 \\\\
r_1 \\\\
r_2 \\\\
r_3 \\\\
r_4 \\\\
k
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there a better way to formulate this type of situation, or is this a known type of problem with a standard solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible arrangement to determine the optimal $c$.

$
\cases{
p_{12} = (p_1, \ p_2)'\\
p_{35} = (p_3, \ p_4, \ p_5)'\\
q_{12} = (q_1, \ q_2)'\\
q_{35} = (q_3, \ q_4, \ q_5)'\\
P_{12}=\unicode{x1D7D9}_2-\ulcorner p_{12}\lrcorner\\
P_{35}=\unicode{x1D7D9}_3-\ulcorner p_{35}\lrcorner\\
Q_{12}=\unicode{x1D7D9}_2-\ulcorner q_{12}\lrcorner\\
Q_{35}=\unicode{x1D7D9}_3-\ulcorner q_{35}\lrcorner\\
u_{12} = (u_1, \ u_2)'\\
u_{35} = (u_3, \ u_4, \ u_5)'\\
v_{12} = (v_1, \ v_2)'\\
v_{35} = (v_3, \ v_4, \ v_5)'\\
r_{12} = (r_1, \ r_2)'\\
r_{35} = (r_3, \ r_4, \ r_5)'\\
t_{12} = (t_1, \ t_2)'\\
t_{35} = (t_3, \ t_4, \ t_5)'\\
}
$

Now to minimize $L(U,V,c)$

$$
L(U,V,c)=\|P_{12}u_{12}-Q_{12}v_{12}+c r_{12}-t_{12}\|^2+\|P_{25}u_{25}-Q_{25}v_{25}+c r_{25}-t_{25}\|^2
$$

the stationary conditions are

$$
\cases{
\frac{\partial L}{\partial u_{12}}=P'_{12}(P_{12}u_{12}-Q_{12}v_{12}+c r_{12}-t_{12})=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_{12}}=Q'_{12}(P_{12}u_{12}-Q_{12}v_{12}+c r_{12}-t_{12})=0
}
$$

$$
\cases{
\frac{\partial L}{\partial u_{35}}=P'_{35}(P_{35}u_{35}-Q_{35}v_{35}+c r_{35}-t_{35})=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_{35}}=Q'_{35}(P_{35}u_{35}-Q_{35}v_{35}+c r_{35}-t_{35})=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}=r'_{12}(P_{12}u_{12}-Q_{12}v_{12}+c r_{12}-t_{12})+r'_{35}(P_{35}u_{35}-Q_{35}v_{35}+c r_{35}-t_{35})=0\\
}
$$

or

$$
\left[\matrix{P'_{12}P_{12}&-P'_{12}Q_{12}&0&0& P'_{12}r_{12}\\
              -Q'_{12}P_{12}&Q'_{12}Q_{12}&0&0& -Q'_{12}r_{12}\\
              0 & 0 & P'_{35}P_{35}&-P'_{35}Q_{35}&P'_{35}r_{35}\\
              0 & 0 & -Q'_{35}P_{35}&Q'_{35}Q_{35}&-Q'_{35}r_{35}\\
              r'_{12}P_{12}&-r'_{12}Q_{12}& r'_{35}P_{35}&-r'_{35}Q_{35}&r'_{12}r_{12}+r'_{35}r_{35}
}\right]\left[\matrix{u_{12}\\ v_{12}\\ u_{35}\\ v_{35}\\ c}\right]=\left[\matrix{P'_{12}t_{12}\\ -Q'_{12}t_{12}\\ P'_{35}t_{35}\\ -Q'_{35}t_{35}\\ r'_{12}t_{12}+r'_{35}t_{35}}\right]
$$

Solving this linear system for $U,V,c$ will furnish us the best $c$.